# What are good references for learning about Biophysics at graduate level?

Tags: resource-recommendations, biophysics

I am graduating this year on both Physics and Mathematics and I want to pursue a career in research, more concretely I want to study Biophysics.

I've been recommended Boal's [Mechanics of the Cell](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl5fDno7jJAhXIPhQKHSz5AEMQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FMechanics-Cell-David-Boal%2Fdp%2F0521130697&usg=AFQjCNHvJzS9oRA1OJd_ED6U-PKaSjkUHQ&sig2=Vf36hyft1lPu7esI8_7-tA) and I think that it is a good book after giving it a look but I would like to know if there is any sort of canonical reference on the field.

I would like a book as mathematical as possible but at the same time my background is very limited when it comes to biology so I would like it to explain the basic and fundamental biological concepts behind the physics.

Answer (score 3):

**[Quantitative Human Physiology: An Introduction](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cDYMIzdJn9sC&redir_esc=y)** By Joseph Feher (link to google books)

Although the content is (obviously) designed towards physiology rather then biophysics, his mathematical treatment of the some of the main concepts in biophysics (e.g. the Nernst equation) is the best that I have come across. The downside is that it does not cover a wide range of topics in biophysics.

**[Biophysics Problems: A Textbook with Answers](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Biophysics_Problems.html?id=RLETAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)** P.Maroti, L.Berkes, F.Tolgyesi

This is simply a collection of problems with solutions (thats it), which depending on your learning style may be helpful. It covers a wide topics from membranes to medical imaging, but the number of questions on each topic is limited.

**[Biochemistry](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Biochemistry.html?id=PPrNoAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)** By D.Voet, J.Voet

Don't be put of by the title. This book covers a wide range of topics in biophysics, and was the set book for my biophysics course. In my opinion this is not as readable* as Feher, but does cover a wider range of topics.

<sub>* That said I am dyslexic, so I wouldn't really take my word on if something is 'readable'.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There are, thankfully, some excellent biophysics textbooks written in the last few years. For a few paragraphs I wrote on several of them, see https://eighteenthelephant.wordpress.com/2015/12/28/recap-of-a-graduate-biophysics-course-part-ii/
Of the ones mentioned there, Bialek's book is the most mathematical, if that's what you want.