# Biophysics book for a physicist

Tags: resource-recommendations, biophysics

I read Phillips et al *Physical biology of the cell*. Though I enjoyed it, I felt it was too slow and light on the mathematical side. Since I studied physics, I would like to see a book more geared towards physicists, that are comfortable with the required mathematics, and know some biology (but not a lot).

Can anyone suggest a title like this?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221417/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Bill Bialek's "Biophysics: Searching for Principles." It's not as broadly informative as Phillip et al.'s book, but it's certainly higher level, designed as a graduate textbook. A few other comments I wrote a while ago are [here](https://eighteenthelephant.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/readings-in-biophysics-part-i/).